# Extracting the simd-vector length from a template parameter to use for a local type

Tags: c++, templates, clang, simd, metal

I'm struggling to find the right C++/clang utterance to solve the following problem. Notice first that the following doesn't overflow the unsigned short because of integer promotions before the arithmetic happens.

```
unsigned short testme = 16320;
testme = testme * 257 / 64;
```

The result is 65535. But when I use simd to try something similar on a vector of unsigned shorts, it doesn't work:

```
#import <simd/simd.h>

template <typename T>
  void muldiv( T* data, unsigned multiply, unsigned divide)
{
    *data = (*data * multiply) / divide;
}

...

simd::ushort4 testme = 16320;
muldiv( &testme, 257, 64);
```

This gives a vector of four 1023's. No integer promotion happened and the multiply wrapped. After looking about in the clang docs, the best I could come up with is this. Notice the caller has to provide a dummy parameter just to provide the working precision as a template type parameter.

```
#import <simd/simd.h>

template <typename T, typename W>
 void muldiv( T* data, unsigned multiply, unsigned divide, W workingtype)
{
    *data = __builtin_convertvector( (__builtin_convertvector(*data, W) * multiply) / divide, T);
}

...

simd::ushort4 testme = 16320;
muldiv( &testme, 257, 64, simd::uint4());
```

Now I get a vector of four 65535's. The reason T is a template parameter is sometimes I pass ushort4, ushort8, ushort16, etc. But I find it ugly to pass the working precision as a parameter as it is always unsigned int. I can't figure out a way to extract the simd-length from T so I can declare the type W locally. Something like this within the function would be nice:

```
typedef unsigned int W __attribute__((__vector_size__( ?? )));
```

But I can't figure out how to make that work. I tried something like this:

```
bool hopeful = __is_convertible_to( simd::ushort4, simd::uint4);
```

But hopeful always returns false.

Can anyone tell me the magic I need?

Note this is on Apple platforms which provides <simd/simd.h>.

Comment: Does simd not have any kind of traits for the different vector types ? If not then maybe you could roll your own ?

Comment: Is this metal `namespace simd`?

Comment: Did you try writing a trait that matches on `__attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)))`, `__attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)))` etc, and that copies it to a new type?

Comment: A simple `sizeof`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Where is your `simd::uint4` defined? Also, I assume that very often upcasting is not the most efficient solution. Instead of `testme * 257 / 64` I would calculate `(testme << 2) + (testme >> 6)`

Comment: @chtz Sorry I forgot to clarify that simd::uint4 comes from <simd/simd.h>, an Apple provided header--and hence to clarify that this is an Apple platforms question. Further the 257 and 64 values are just samples to illustrate the point. I edited the question above to clarify.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I don't think sizeof helps. T may be simd::ushort4 say or simd::uint2--half as many at twice the size.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont <simd/simd.h> is the same facility as available in Metal but made available outside of Metal.

Comment: Same as computing the number of elements of an array: `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` or something like that.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Of course that would work Marc. Sorry and thanks for the suggestion. The accepted answer gets me the type though which is what I need for __builtin_convertvector(). I don't think the __attribute__(()) stuff works at run time.

Comment: sizeof is compile-time and works just fine in an attribute.

Comment: @MarcGlisse You had to hit me over the head with this but the following works. Post an answer and I'll upvote it:  constexpr size_t card = sizeof(*data)/sizeof((*data).x);
 using W = __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(card))) unsigned int;

Comment: @MarcGlisse though you should mention that non-packed types like ushort3 won't work like the above as there's a short of padding.

Comment: Ah, I didn't consider such uneven vectors, I am more used to gcc which doesn't support them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So clang lets you pattern match on attributes and generate new attribute-modified types in templates.

So we can do this.

First pattern match on the simd width attribute:

```
template<class T>
struct get_simd_width;

template<class T, std::size_t x>
struct get_simd_width< __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(x))) T >:
  std::integral_constant<std::size_t, x>
{};
```

Also, extract the underlying type of an attributed type:

```
template<class T>
struct get_simd_type;

template<class T, std::size_t x>
struct get_simd_type< __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(x))) T >
{
  using type = T;
};
```

We then do some syntactic sugar to make them easier to use:

```
template<class T>
constexpr std::size_t simd_width = get_simd_width<T>{};
template<class T>
using simd_type = typename get_simd_type<T>::type;
```

This is to generate a new simd type with an attribute:

```
template<class T>
struct simd_helper;
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct simd_helper<T[N]> {
  using type = __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(N))) T;
};
template<class T>
using simd = typename simd_helper<T>::type;
```

Then `simd<int[4]>` makes a width-4 simd type.

Those should solve your problem.  [Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Enxe1a).

```
template <class T>
void muldiv( T* data, unsigned multiply, unsigned divide)
{
   using W = simd<int[simd_width<T>]>;
   *data = __builtin_convertvector( (__builtin_convertvector(*data, W) * multiply) / divide, T);
}
```

Comment: Wow, this works but I don't yet understand it. Marking correct while I figure out. Thanks!

Comment: @Mustang I checked, and you can type match on the simd attributes in clang: so I did and extracted their value.  Similarly, you can use templates to create attribute-modified types.

Comment: @Mustang So I added descriptions of each type, and removed the crappy `simd` one for the good one.

Comment: @Adam thanks for the additional notes. Any advice on the best text for mastering meta-programming like this?

Comment: @Mustang Almost any non-intro C++ book of any quality?  https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/by60wx/modern_c_authors_and_books/ is probably good